# Unable to access my deployed application through brower

Tags: maven, tomcat8.5

Installed maven and tomcat on same RHEL server. Then deployed a war file to tomcat successfully, but unable to access the app on browser.

Tried accessing the url as mentioned in `pom.xml`, but no luck.

`http://ip-addr:8080/manager/text/myapp`

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.home.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>simple-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
     <!-- https://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning -->
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
     <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
 </properties>

  <build>
     <plugins>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
             <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.2</version>
             <configuration>
                 <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                 <server>TomcatServer</server>
                 <path>/myapp</path>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>

         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.3</version>
             <configuration>
                 <outputDirectory>/opt/tomcat8/webapps</outputDirectory>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

created maven project with below configuration.

`mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.home.app -DartifactId=simple-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false`

which by default has sample code as below.

```
package com.home.app;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

After deployment able to see war file in `/opt/tomcat8/webapps` folder too.

```
docs  examples  host-manager  manager  myapp  myapp.war  ROOT
```

so, when accessed like below, it should show my app.

`http://ip-addr:8080/myapp`  or

`http://ip-addr:8080/manager/text/myapp`

it's not showing the expected `Hello World!` message.

How can i fix it?

Comment: That a web application is different to a Java SE application is known to you?

Comment: I don't have any java background. Am actually trying to learn maven!

Comment: Learning maven by trying to build a web application with tomcat is like learning to use a hammer by trying to build a house. Skip tomcat and try to build a Java SE application using maven!